# Update TextArea while executing processes

Tags: user-interface, javafx, concurrency, updates, fxml

i found out that my GUI starts to freeze after 3-4 seconds when I click the "start" button like "no response". When I keep on click the App, it's forced to shut down.
Now I want to prevent this but I got no clue how. Just as far as I know JavaFX runs in a Single Thread, therefore, to update my TextArea while the Methods are executing, I need to run these Methods in another Thread.
I hope someone can help me.

**How does my project look like?**

I got a FXML, a Controller, a Handler, a Transformer , also a Writer and a Reader class (which are used in the Handler class).
When I click the button, which is bind to a method in the Controller, an instance of Handler is created and this one calls the Reader to read in a text file, transformed to a List of Strings (line by line).
In addition, the lines are getting manipulated. After this, the Writer is used to creat a new file and write the new manipulated lines to this file.
It is also allowed to the user to refer to more than just one file.
What I want is that the textarea shows whenever the reader starts to read a file like "The file ... is being read".
Then append "The file ... is being manipulated" when Transformer comes to action and then
"The file ... is being written" when the new lines are written to the new file.

**Here is some code..**
**Controller:**

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private TextArea console;

@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    System.out.println("You clicked me!");
    Handler hand = new Handler();
    hand.handle(files);
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}    

}
```

**Handler:**

```
public class Handler {

public void handle(List<String> files) {
    for (String s : files) {
        List<String> ls = Reader.readFile(s);
        Writer.writeFile(Transformer.transform(ls));
    }
}
```

How should I change my code to update the TextArea whenever a file is read, manipulated or written?

***Info***: I know the class Handler won't compile as I erased the initialization of the List "files" which contains Strings of file paths.

If I left out relevant information, feel free to ask.
I thank you in advance!

Comment: You should be looking at Tasks and Services in the concurrency package: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm. And [Platform.runLater()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should execute the `handle()` method in a background thread:

```
@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    System.out.println("You clicked me!");

    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        Handler hand = new Handler();
        hand.handle(files);
    });

    // this line means the background thread will not prevent application exit:
    thread.setDaemon(true);

    thread.start();
}
```

If you want to update the text area with the current status, you need to schedule that back on the FX Application Thread using `Platform.runLater()`. Probably the cleanest way to do this is not to have `Platform.runLater()` in the `Handler` class, but define a field in `Handler` for "consuming" status messages:

```
public class Handler {

    private final Consumer<String> statusMessageProcessor ;

    public Handler(Consumer<String> statusMessageProcessor) {
        this.statusMessageProcessor = statusMessageProcessor ;
    }

    // default processor does nothing:
    public Handler() {
        this(s -> {});
    }

    public void handle(List<String> files) {
        for (String s : files) {

            // similarly for other status updates:
            statusMessageProcessor.accept("The file "+s+" is being read");

            List<String> ls = Reader.readFile(s);
            Writer.writeFile(Transformer.transform(ls));
        }
    }
}
```

and then

```
Handler hand = new Handler() ;
```

can become

```
Handler hand = new Handler(message -> 
    Platform.runLater(() -> console.appendText(message + "\n")));
```

in the button handler method.

Comment: I would prefer the second way, no? As I can see the state when a file is read, manipulated and written which I cant see in the first variant.  s in Handler hand = new Handler(s -> Platform.runLater(() -> console.appendText(s+"\n"))); is my initialized list?

Comment: What do you mean? There is only one solution here. I just broke it into two pieces to be more understandable: first, how to run the handler in the background thread, and second, how to provide updates.

Comment: `s` in the call to the `Handler` constructor is just the name of the parameter to the lambda (so it is the status message being passed to `statusMessageProcessor.accept(...)`). You can call it anything you want (obviously if you change it, also change the use of it inside `console.appendText(...)`).

Comment: Thank you! I deleted "Handler hand = new Handler();" and copied "Handler hand = new Handler(s -> Platform.runLater(() -> console.appendText(s+"\n")));" before the Thread declaration and it's working fine now! Concurrency is a very complex topic and I never know what implementation i should use (thread, task, backgroundworker, consumer, service, ...). Could you give a me link or advice? Is there a design pattern which supports thread implementations in special? Edit: Im sorry, can upvote you as Im missing 5 rep points..

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct (you don't need reputation for that) if it answers the question. Use a `Task` if the background task computes a result which you want to show in the UI (or if you want to change the UI on completion). You could use a `Task<Void>` for this but there is little benefit over a simple runnable for the usage you have described. Use a `Service` if you want to be able to restart the task multiple times.

Comment: Ok that answered everything. Thanks.